# According to limits there is a horizontal asymptote at y = 0, however the equation has a root at x = 1.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

So I have the equation $$f(x)=\frac{(x-1)}{x^2}$$

This clearly has a root when $x=1$ however when considering limits we have the following $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$$

And similarly $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=0$$

Which implies there is horizontal asymptote when $f(x)=0$

However this is clearly not the case since the function crosses the $y$-axis.

Have I made a mistake somewhere or is this a case where the definition of horizontal asymptotes doesn't work (or do I have the wrong definition!).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A horizontal asymptote only tells you that it tends to a certain value as $x$ goes to infinity in some direction. It can certainly cross the asymptote any number of times without contradicting this, including infinitely many times. For example, 
$$f(x) =\frac{\sin x} x$$
has a horizontal asymptote at $y=0$, but continually crosses the asymptote as $x$ approaches infinity.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the function does not cross the $y$-axis due to the singularity at $x=0$, which makes $f(x)$ discontinuous. For $x>0$, $f(x)$ crosses $x=1$ while still approaching the horizontal asymptote.

[image]

Comment: The function is not discontinuous. It is continuous on its domain.